# comparing the numbers present in two files and get the matched numbers using perl programming

Tags: perl

i need to compare the numbers present in two files.

for example in **file1.txt**:

> human
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

and in another **file2.txt**:

> human
>
> 1 2 3 8 0 7 6

the above two files should be given as input.
and the output will be as:

1 2 3 6 7 8 (i.e. the matching numbers) if possible the output must come in another file.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you clarify what you mean by matching?  Is the fact that the numbers you say match are in the same position in both files important, or is mere presence anywhere in the file a match?  (I think your formatting of the sample data might need a little edit btw.)

Comment: presence anywhere in the file.

Comment: matching of each numbers in both the files

Answer (score 5):

1. Go buy Learning Perl
2. Read each chapter and complete the excercises
3. Solve this problem for yourself

If this is homework:

1. Read your textbooks and other class materials.
2. Show up for class.
3. Stay awake during lectures.
4. Take effective notes.
5. Ask your TAs or professor for help with things you don't understand.
6. Solve this problem for yourself

In any case, there is a lovely set of [tutorials in perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html), not to mention [a very useful index of functions by category](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-functions-by-cat.html).